# How to apply a function which replaces a string in a particular way to python dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to come up with a function that replaces a string 
'ORG_CD_XXX > 0.00' with 'ORG_CD_XXX'

This string can occur anywhere in the given dataframe rows. I am trying to come up with a function that does that replacement but when I try to apply it to the dataframe series I get the error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Rule': 
                ['HAD_MAA_PM and HAD_MAA_PM and ACH_PERC_PM > 66.64 and ACH_PERC_CM > 82.19'
                 ,'HAD_MAA_PM and HAD_MAA_PM and ORG_CD_DDV > 0.00 and ACH_PERC_CM > 82.19'
                 ,'HAD_MAA_PM and HAD_MAA_PM and ORG_CD_DDV > 0.00 and ach_perc_chg_CM <= 0.00 and ACH_PERC_PPM > 48.99']
                }
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

def org_cd_replace(text):
    text1=text.split('ORG_CD_')
    text2=[item.replace(' > 0.00',"",1) for item in text1]
    text3=text2[0]+'ORG_CD_'+text2[1]

    return text3

df['Rule'].apply(lambda x:org_cd_replace(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. The problem you have here is because some strings don't have `'ORG_CD_'` in them. 
To tackle this, just add a test :

```
def org_cd_replace(text):
    if 'ORG_CD_' in text:
        text1=text.split('ORG_CD_')
        text2=[item.replace(' > 0.00','', 1) for item in text1]
        text3=text2[0]+'ORG_CD_'+text2[1]
        return text3
    return text

df = pd.DataFrame(df['Rule'].apply(lambda x:org_cd_replace(x)))
```

You have to add the pd.DataFrame() call at the end to get a DataFrame after applying a lambda function. 
There's no doubt there is a better way (more efficient at least) to do this though.

Comment: Thank you Charles, the solution was under my very nose. Thanks for pointing it to me.